More vertical space after description and enumitem?
With the following example, I would like to slightly increase the vertical spacing between the description item and the text. I did not find such option in the documentation. Is there a way?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlist[description]{
  style=nextline,
  leftmargin=0.7cm,
  itemindent=\dimexpr-5pt-\labelsep\relax
}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
  \item[Duck] A waterbird with a broad blunt bill, short legs, webbed feet, and a waddling gait.
  \item[Seagull] A large, common, and very widespread long-winged seabird with a raucous call.
  \item[Goose] A waterbird with a long neck, short legs, webbed feet, and a short broad bill.
\end{description}
\end{document}



Add a deep strut to \descriptionlabel.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\AddToHook{cmd/descriptionlabel/after}{\rule[-8pt]{0pt}{0pt}}
\setlist[description]{
  style=nextline,
  leftmargin=0.7cm,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
\item[Duck] A waterbird with a broad blunt bill,
  short legs, webbed feet, and a waddling gait.
\item[Seagull] A large, common, and very widespread
  long-winged seabird with a raucous call.
\item[Goose] A waterbird with a long neck, short legs,
  webbed feet, and a short broad bill.
\end{description}

\end{document}

The setting of itemindent does nothing.

I'd not and rather reduce the indent.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlist[description]{
  style=nextline,
  leftmargin=1em,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
\item[Duck] A waterbird with a broad blunt bill,
  short legs, webbed feet, and a waddling gait.
\item[Seagull] A large, common, and very widespread
  long-winged seabird with a raucous call.
\item[Goose] A waterbird with a long neck, short legs,
  webbed feet, and a short broad bill.
\end{description}

\end{document}


